# SQL SUM COUNT CASE

Tags: mysql, sql, hive

I'm working on some transaction analysis.
I want to see the no of transactions by quantities per transaction.
Below is the data and result wanted.

```
table name: trans_cust

store_id  trans_id  product    qty
A            123     milk       1
A            123    chocolate   1
A            123    candy       1
A            456    milk        4
A            789    candy       1
B            321    chocolate   3
B            321    napkin      1
B            654   blueberry    2
C            987    candy       6

Result

Quantity    num_Transaction
1               1
2               1
3               1
4+              3
```

I have the below try out, but it doesn't work out.

```
select count(distinct(trans_id)) as num_transation, case
when sum(quantity) = 1 then '1'
when sum(quantity) = 2 then '2'
when sum(quantity) = 3 then '3'
when sum(quantity)>= 5 then '5+' else 'other' end as Quantity

from (select sum(quantity) as Quantity from trans_cust)
```

Could you all please help? Thank you.

Comment: Seems like a derived table would be handy.

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: Hive. the above table is a very simplified version. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT CASE WHEN s.quantity >= 4 THEN '4+' 
            WHEN s.quantity = 1 THEN '1'
            WHEN s.quantity = 2 THEN '2'
            WHEN s.quantity = 3 THEN '3'
       END as quantity
      ,count(*)
FROM (
    SELECT t.trans_id,sum(t.quantity) as quantity 
    FROM trans_cust t
    group by t.trans_id) s
GROUP BY CASE WHEN s.quantity >= 4 THEN '4+' 
            WHEN s.quantity = 1 THEN '1'
            WHEN s.quantity = 2 THEN '2'
            WHEN s.quantity = 3 THEN '3'
       END
```

Making this a varchar column makes the code a bit messy, you could also do :

```
SELECT p.quantity,count(*) FROM (
    SELECT CASE WHEN s.quantity >= 4 THEN '4+' 
                WHEN s.quantity = 1 THEN '1'
                WHEN s.quantity = 2 THEN '2'
                WHEN s.quantity = 3 THEN '3'
           END as quantity
    FROM (
        SELECT t.trans_id,sum(t.quantity) as quantity 
        FROM trans_cust t
        group by t.trans_id) s) p
GROUP BY p.quantity
```